# How to inject the dbContext into iLogger

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, dependency-injection

I trying to inject the ApplicationDbcontext into iLogger.

When I use `_context variable` inside the `CustomLoggerProvider` or `CustomLoggerExtension` it'is **work**.

While when the software `CreateLogger` create a instance of `CustomLogger`, I have a problem with `ApplicationDbContext`, when I use the `_context` variable to access the database the application crashes and **doesn't work**.

The following there is the error log:

> System.ObjectDisposedException   HResult=0x80131622   Messaggio=Cannot
>   access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a
>   context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later
>   trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application.
>   This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or
>   wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency
>   injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care
>   of disposing context instances.
>
> Origine=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore   Analisi dello stack:    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Add[TEntity](TEntity entity)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Add(TEntity
>   entity)    at Application.Services.EventLogDB.saveInDb(Cliente c)  28 
>   at Application.Models.DbLogger.CustomLogger.Log[TState](LogLevel
>   logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3
>   formatter) in C:\Users......\Models\DbLogger\CustomLogger.cs:line 122
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.g__LoggerLog|12_0[TState](LogLevel
>   logLevel, EventId eventId, ILogger logger, Exception exception, Func`3
>   formatter, List`1& exceptions, TState& state)

I think it's a problem of the service life cycle.

Is there anyone who knows a solution?

### Startup.cs :

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        var serviceHttp = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var serviceDbContext = serviceProvider.GetService<GestionaleOfficinaContext>();

        // THIS IS METHOD THAT SHOWS THE BAD BEHAVIOUR
        // Inside logger I need of Http context service and applicationDbContext
        loggerFactory.AddCustomLogger(serviceHttp, serviceDbContext);
    }
}
```

### CustomLogger.cs :

```
public static class CustomLoggerExtensions
{
    public static ILoggerFactory AddCustomLogger(this ILoggerFactory factory, IHttpContextAccessor accessor, ApplicationDbContext_context,
                                          Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter = null)
    {
        factory.AddProvider(new CustomLogProvider(filter, accessor, _context));
        return factory;
    }
}

public class CustomLogProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly Func<string, LogLevel, bool> _filter;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext_context;

    public CustomLogProvider(Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter, IHttpContextAccessor accessor, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _filter = filter;
        _accessor = accessor;
        _context = context;

        // IF I USE THE variable _context in this place of code the applicationDbContext is available
        // and so the behaviour is right

        //if (_context != null)
        //{
        //    Cliente cl = new Cliente();
        //    cl.codiceFiscale = "ALFA";
        //
        //    _context.Add(cl);
        //    _context.SaveChanges();
        //}

    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        // In this part of code there is the strange behaviour
        // _context is different by null, but when I use _context
        // the lifetime of service ApplicationDbContext is END
        if (_context != null)
        {
            Cliente cl = new Cliente();
            cl.codiceFiscale = "CCC";

            _context.Add(cl);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return new CustomLogger(categoryName, _filter, _accessor, _context);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //base.Dispose();
    }
}

// THE ERROR IS IN THIS CLASS
public class CustomLogger : ILogger
{
    private string _categoryName;
    private Func<string, LogLevel, bool> _filter;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    private readonly GestionaleOfficinaContext _context;

    public CustomLogger(string categoryName, Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter, IHttpContextAccessor accessor, GestionaleOfficinaContext context)
    {
        _categoryName = categoryName;
        _filter = filter;
        _accessor = accessor;
        _context = context;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return (_filter == null || _filter(_categoryName, logLevel));
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (formatter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(formatter));
        }

        var message = formatter(state, exception);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            return;
        }

        message = $"{ logLevel }: {message}";
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception were thrown?

Comment: In the `Startup` `Configure` method you retrieve a `context`, but do you also `bind` this (in `DI` terms) in the first place? I mean this line: `var serviceDbContext = serviceProvider.GetService<GestionaleOfficinaContext>();`

Comment: Always include the exact error message , error number and stacktrace.

Comment: Hi guys, 
@agee I don't execute the bind but the function getService, this logic is right because when the method AddCustomLogger is called the variable _context is populated and work in perfect way

Comment: @HenkHotlerman The error is this:

System.ObjectDisposedException
  HResult=0x80131622
  Messaggio=Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.